# What do I need to send SMS to a client cellphone from my hosted server?

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I am working on my school project, which is sending SMS to a client from hosted server or from local server,
using any open source SMS API like [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) etc.

My question is: Do need a special kind of modem to do this or what else would be needed to send SMS to a client.

Comment: The only thing you need is a server with a working SMTP (when I work for small project I like to use my personal Gmail SMTP but most of the time your server provider give you SMTP pass).

Comment: Kannel? Sure you don't want a real sms-gateway

Comment: @dagon do i need any gsm modem for kannel to work ?

Comment: im saying don't use Kannel at all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a GSM/3G modem to send SMS via Kannel, but it might be tricky to setup and it's not for high traffic. It's option one.

Better, if you find some gateway like Email-2-SMS or HTTP-2-SMS like OneAPI. It will be much easier.

After a little thought. If you insist on Kannel you can connect it to some SMPP simulator like [SMPPSim](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/user-guide.htm) or [smppsink](https://github.com/PowerMeMobile/smppsink). Then when your logic is ready setup GSM modem.